# I can't update the craft CMS. Returns an error

Tags: craft4, updates

CRAFT CMS 4.5 has been released. I have updated to this version calmly. There are new updates 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.5.3. But when trying to update the system, it gives this error:

> Ошибка: The command "'/opt/php82/bin/php'
> '/home/c/cf74574/fmedia.info/storage/runtime/composer.phar' 'update'
> 'craftcms/cms' '--with-all-dependencies' '--working-dir'
> '/home/c/cf74574/fmedia.info' '--no-scripts' '--no-ansi'
> '--no-interaction'" failed.
>
> Exit Code: 1(General error)
>
> Working directory: /home/c/cf74574/fmedia.info/public_html
>
> Output:
>
> Error Output:
>
> In Factory.php line 697:
>
> The HOME or COMPOSER_HOME environment variable must be set for
> composer to run correctly update [--with WITH] [--prefer-source]
> [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--dry-run] [--dev]
> [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format
> AUDIT-FORMAT] [--no-autoloader] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress]
> [-w|--with-dependencies] [-W|--with-all-dependencies]
> [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]
> [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader]
> [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX]
> [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs]
> [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs]
> [--] [...]
>
> Вывод компоновщика: In Factory.php line 697:
>
> The HOME or COMPOSER_HOME environment variable must be set for
> composer to run correctly update [--with WITH] [--prefer-source]
> [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--dry-run] [--dev]
> [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format
> AUDIT-FORMAT] [--no-autoloader] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress]
> [-w|--with-dependencies] [-W|--with-all-dependencies]
> [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]
> [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader]
> [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX]
> [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs]
> [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs]
> [--] [...]

Please help me to sort out the problem. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the same problem I had once, but it looks similar.
If you are running the update as a terminal command, my hosting company (running cPanel) suggested I ran this line of code in the terminal straight after I logged in and before doing anything else to set the location of composer.

```
alias composer='ea-php81 /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer'
```

I'm not a sysadmin and only use the terminal when I have to, so this may not apply to your hosting setup. But it might give you a start in finding the solution.